# Tool for selecting window by searching in X11?

Tags: linux, xorg, window-manager

I often have many windows open on many virtual desktops and I have hard time finding some application.

So is there any tool for searching  open windows?

Currently I using Awesome as my window manager, but it does not need to be dependent on it.

Answer (score 2):

I use `dmenu`.

An script in my `~/bin` called `go-win`

```
#!/bin/bash
wmctrl -l | cut -d' ' -f5- | dmenu -nb '#3f3f3f' -nf '#dcdccc' -sf '#3f3f3f' -sb '#dcdccc' -i | xargs wmctrl -a
```

and a global key in my `rc.lua`

```
awful.key({ modkey }, "g", function() exec("go-win") end)
```

Using that you'll get the list of open windows on the top of screen, and it does incremental search as you type.

Comment: This is a great solution when using single monitor, but with dual head system it cannot distinguish between monitors. ie. it activates wrong virtual desktop in Awesome (in awesome every screen has its own virtual desktops).

Answer (score 1):

KDE 4 has a standard program, Krunner, that will do this (among other things - basically it works like [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/)). I don't know whether it would work with a different window manager/desktop environment, but I figured I'd mention it in case you wanted to give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

With the [Sawfish](http://sawfish.wikia.com/) window manager (a stacking manager extensible in Scheme), I like [iswitch-window](http://sawfish.wikia.com/wiki/Iswitch-window). Press the shortcut key, then a few letters in the window name, and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

A [similar interface for Gnome](http://www.mail-archive.com/deskbar-applet-list@gnome.org/msg00403.html), [iswitch-window.py](http://www.travishartwell.net/projects/iswitch-window/), is included in the [DeskBar applet](http://projects.gnome.org/deskbar-applet/).

I'd be surprised, even a little disappointed, if Awesome didn't have something similar. If not, you could always write it in Lua.

You could implement a similar feature in a window manager-agnostic way in a text terminal using a shell's completion mechanism (zsh, or perhaps bash) and the `wmctrl` command.